# Unable to contact your Apache Solr server

Tags: solr, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-extensions

I have a problem with an old TYPO3 installation (TYPO3 site 7 LTS [7.6.9]).

The site is using Apache Solr as the search engine, but it's not working. When a user tries to search, the system shows a message telling that the search engine is not available now.

In the administration panel, if I go to the Search option, I see this message:

> Unable to contact your Apache Solr server.
>   Hosts missing:
> http://localhost:8080/solr/core_es/
>   http://localhost:8080/solr/core_eu/
>   http://localhost:8080/solr/core_en/

Of course, I have checked that Solr is running and listening on the port 8080. The Solr server is on the same machine than TYPO3.

I found [this link](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/10.0/en-us/GettingStarted/ConfigureExtension.html) about the Apache Solr configuration, but I cannot find these administration pages. I would like to test with the machine's public IP. In fact, I changed all the records regarding Solr in the **cf_tx_solr_configuration** table, and cleared all the cache tables manually, with no effect.

I have a couple of questions here:

1. Is it possible to change the configuration of the Solr server in TYPO3? If so, how can I do that?
2. Is TYPO3 shipped with an out-of-the-box search feature? If so, how can I disable Apache Solr and use the default search engine?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

please consume appropriate documentation Version of installed Extension.

So I assume(see [Version Mati](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/master/Documentation/Appendix/VersionMatrix.rst)x) you are using EXT:Solr version 6.5, therefore you must use the [documentation for EXT:Solr v. 6.5](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/6.5/en-us/Index.html).

--
QA

> 1. Is it possible to change the configuration of the Solr server in TYPO3? If so, how can I do that?

Yes, it is. You can set it via TypoScript path ["plugin.tx_solr.solr.scheme|host|port|..."](https://docs.typo3.org/p/apache-solr-for-typo3/solr/6.5/en-us/Configuration/Reference/TxSolrSolr.html)

> 2. Is TYPO3 shipped with an out-of-the-box search feature? If so, how can I disable Apache Solr and use the default search engine?

Yes, TYPO3 has build in search feature. Its name is [indexed_search](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/indexed_search/7.6/).

PS: You know, there are much more modern versions of TYPO3 available? Please upgrade at least to the newer major release.

Comment: Thanks so much, Rafael! I'll try that and let you know if it's working.